# Why I get indexoutofRangeException

Tags: unity

I am not sure why, for the below code, I keep getting `IndexoutofRangeException` for the variable `ResistorBand2`? The error is pointing to the line `ResistorBand2[0]=Random.Range(1,10)` and I cannot spot the error.

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class AdvanceWayPoint : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform player;
        bool CreateResistor;
        int RandNum;
        public GameObject myprefab;
        public GameObject FloatingText;
        public GameObject Resistor;
        public GameObject[] way1;
        public int[] ResistorBand;
        public int[] ResistorBand2;
        public float ResistorValue;
        public float ResistorValue2;

        void Start()
        {
            Random.InitState(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            CreateResistor = true;
        }
 
        void Update()
        {
            if (CreateResistor == true)
            {
                Count(1);
                CreateResistor = false;
                Waypoint();
            }
        }

        public void Waypoint()
        {
            Vector3 SpawnPosition = player.transform.position;
            Vector3 ExactSpawnPoint = new Vector3(SpawnPosition.x + Random.Range(1, 10), 0, SpawnPosition.z + Random.Range(1, 10));
            Vector3 ExactResistorSpawnPoint = new Vector3(ExactSpawnPoint.x+Random.Range(1,4), ExactSpawnPoint.y+7, ExactSpawnPoint.z+Random.Range(1,4));
        
            if (RandNum == 1)
            {
                for (int g = 0; g < 2; g++)
                {
                    ResistorBand[0] = Random.Range(1, 10);
                    ResistorBand[1] = Random.Range(1, 10);
                    ResistorBand[2] = Random.Range(1, 5);
                    ResistorBand[3] = Random.Range(1, 3) * 5;
                    ResistorValue = ((ResistorBand[0] * 10 + ResistorBand[1]) * Mathf.Pow(10, ResistorBand[2]) / 1000);
                    Debug.Log("RUN");
                    Instantiate(Resistor, ExactResistorSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                }

                way1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("1K ohm");
                Debug.Log(way1.Length.ToString());
                
                if (way1.Length == 0)
                {
                    ResistorBand2[0] = Random.Range(1, 10);
                    ResistorBand2[1] = Random.Range(1, 10);
                    ResistorBand2[2] = Random.Range(1, 5);
                    ResistorBand2[3] = Random.Range(1, 3) * 5;
                    var go=Instantiate(FloatingText, ExactSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                    Instantiate(myprefab, ExactSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                    go.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ResistorValue.ToString()+" K ohm +/-"+ResistorBand[3].ToString()+"%";
                    Instantiate(Resistor, ExactResistorSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
        }

        public int Count(int number)
        {
            RandNum = number;
            return RandNum;
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Your error aside, the usage of count and random number is neither a count nor a random number :)

Comment: Fixed the error and checked the result indeed it is not a random number XD. In that case, I will try it with perlin noise.

Comment: perlin noise has nothing to do with not a random number. Your `count()` function is assigning the number to randnum, instead you should rather do actually roll your random number (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your class-level arrays:

```
public int[] ResistorBand;
public int[] ResistorBand2;
```

but you aren't initialising them anywhere, like:

```
ResistorBand = new int[7];    // This array has 7 elements
ResistorBand2 = new int[10];  // This one has 10 elements
```

If you don't initialise them, they will have zero length. Trying to access a 0-length array at any position raises an `IndexoutofRangeException` error.

Since your issue only happens with `ResistorBand2`, this means you're actually assigning values to `ResistorBand` in the editor, from the Inspector. You should do the same with `ResistorBand2`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you didn't initialize `ResistorBand2`. here's what you should do:

```cs
int[] ResistorBand2 = new int[4];
```

and by doing so, you shouldn't get the error anymore. but if you want a more easy-to-manage array, you may consider using `List<int>` as you can `add` new members to it:

```cs
List<int> ResistorBand2 = new List<int> { };
// ...
ResistorBand2.Add(Random.Range(1, 10));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any initializations for `public int[] ResistorBand2`. This creates an array, but doesn't put any elements into it.

You're trying to refer to an element that does not exist yet, so you get the "out of range" error.